# List pacman upgradable packages without "-version"

Tags: linux, archlinux, pacman-package-manager

How could I list all packages that need upgrading without the -version postfix in pacman so I can copy paste a portion for pacman -S.

Current output : `acl-2.3.1-3  akonadi-22.12.2-1...etc`
Required output : `acl akonadi...etc`

Thanks.

pacman -Qu & garuda-update; Both list versions in some form.

Comment: What produces your current output of `acl-2.3.1-3  akonadi-22.12.2-1`? `pacman -Q` produces, e.g. `acl 2.3.1-3` with a whitespace between the package name and version with each package on a separate line. Are you talking about the listing from `pacman -Syu`?

Comment: Why not do `pacman -Qeq > list.txt` to capture all explicitly installed packages in `list.txt` and then `pacman -S - < list.txt` to install on another machine (dependencies get pulled in automatically)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin This is close to the solution, however it pulls all packages when I only need upgradable packages. If there is a command that produce the same output syntax but only for upgradable packages it would solve the issue.


As for which command I use, that would be garuda-update (I use garuda, which is arch based, however also pacman native commands also produce versions)

Comment: It you want `list.txt` all on one line, then just `tr '\n' ' ' < list.txt`.  Or to write to a new file `tr '\n' ' ' < list.txt >one-line-list.txt`.

Comment: Okay, then just use `pacman -Quq | tr '\n' ' '` Add `; echo ""` at the end to output a final newline so you don't screw up the next prompt `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command produces the required output.

```
checkupdates | cut -d ' ' -f1 | xargs
```

ps. Partial upgrades aren't recommended, use on your own discretion.